# Issues with Oracle .NET DATA Provider - Looking for other option

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net, oracle9i

Before I start, I advise you to have take a deep breath and understand, this is a very long question and had 3-4 problem in single context. So have patience while reading. (write in comment if you need anything, code sample or whatever as I'm seriously looking for a solution).

Recently I had been working with a client and he wanted to have application database in **Oracle**. The application was built on **ASP.NET MVC**.

We choose **Oracle 11g** express for development environment and client has confirmed the same. We decided to go with [ODAC 32bit .NET Provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html#Table5) which has support for ORM (EF). We first carried out a trial case of implementing CRUD operation and everything worked fine. We then started development of actual client requirement. In 2-3 months the product was ready to be delivered. So till now, everything has been working fine on ASP.NET and Oracle 11g. When we went for deployment and UAT, we came to know that the client is having oracle 9i for his existing ERP which isn't matching with the version we developed. So we searched on internet for verifying if same ODAC provider is compatible with Oracle 9i. We found the references where it was mentioned that it is compatible with Oracle 9i.

We just migrated database to Oracle 9i server, change EF model accordingly and found following issues:

**1. Transaction was not automatically committed!**

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    // some code written here
}
```

The same code was working with 11g and when moved to Oracle 9i it stopped working.Transactions were not auto committing after completion of using statement. We intentionally wrote `transaction.commit();` in the using block and it started working.

Is this expected behavior?

**2. Problem with `VARCHAR2` datatype and ODP NET Provider.**
We had created some stored procedures in the database having `Varchar2` and other db types as parameter. While accessing those stored procedure using ADO.NET style *(OracleConnection, OracleCommand and OracleParameter)*, what we came to know is that the parameters having `VARCHAR2` data type sometime truncates data even if the data passed to parameter is of less size than what table column was given. It just randomly removes number of characters from the end.
[Problem is also logged here in oracle forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/415531/#thread-message-1516121)

**We were not able to find the solution of this.**

**3. Inline query size limit (no of characters).**
For solving the problem mentioned in #2, we realized that we are supposed to convert those stored procedure into inline query and call those using ADO.NET (Old style during school days coding)! We converted all our stored procedures into line scripts and wrote as following

```
OracleCommand command=new OracleCommand("Select * from something",Connection);
```

And used same technique for other DML statements. Now everything was working fine, we carried out UAT and we made the application live. After 10-15 days we found weird problem. If query (inline query) has size of more than 4000 character, then Oracle server throws exception stating that 'Query is too long to execute' (I don't remember the exception or message exactly but it was similar to what I have written). We took the sample data in development environment and debug through code and came to know that the size of SQL query is too long, long more than 32000 to 64000 characters!
We knew that the solution to this was same 'If we can somehow be able to call stored procedures properly!' But we cannot as we do not have any choice.

As a solution, we recreated those stored procedure in database and called those stored procedure inline!

```
OracleCommand command=new OracleCommand("BEGIN ProceduretoCall(Param1,Param2); END;",Connection);
```

And it's working since then.

With above problems in mind,

1. I'm not able to call stored procedure from ASP.NET in usual way (CommandType.StoredProcedure) #problem-1 in above
2. I'm not able to return any data or scalar value or return value from stored procedure after insert or updating. #problem-3 in above
3. I'm not able to use transaction at code level. (It keep saying, a distributed transaction is initialized but actually I don't have distributed transaction at all!)

Why all of above at the end after Go Live?
It was almost nightmare of issues with oracle that I had been solving for a month, one after another and that made me think

Is ODP.NET/ ODAC tool really reliable?

If not then what are other option that I can go with based on your experience? (Please know that ODBC is also having similar problem with Oracle 9i).

I'm more likely to work on similar kind of project in next week and I thought this time I want to be ready with better approach.

Comment: Oracle 9i is not supported. New applications should not be developed against it.

Comment: You should break up your question in pieces. This question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend isolating each of your points as a separate question.  Each one is specific and has it's own questions and it's going to be a mess keeping it all straight.

Second, I agree with the comment.  Even Oracle 10gR1, released in 2003 is unsupported.  Perhaps you need to accept some of the responsibility by not asking this question up front, but I also don't think it's unreasonable for you to also state that they'd be using a supported version of oracle.

That said I'll take a quick stab:

1. TransactionScope never autocommits.  You'd need to add transaction.Complete().  The only unexpected behavior there is WAS committing before.
2. The referenced article mentions that the issue is resolved on recompile of the oracle proceedures and indicates an oracle patchset that resolves the issue.  If that's the case I don't consider this an odp.net issue.  If you want you can paste both the proc signature and how you are adding the parameter to see if there are some tweeks you can try.  But again, I'd post as a separate question.

3.2 - I'm not sure how you were returning scalars anyway - you'd need a refcursor on the parameter and I'm not sure how creating an anonymous block would change that.  Again I think you need to post more of your code, specifically how you are sending the parameters.

3.3 - TransactionScope automatically will convert from a local transaction to a distributed connection when the transaction includes multiple connections, even if they are to the same database.  However, I don't think this feature was supported until 11g, and previously all transactions would have started as distributed.  However, I'm not sure 9i even had that concept which might have explained the strange auto-commit you were seeing.

ODP.net has been completely reliable for me for the last 7 years.  That said, I've always ran it against a supported version of oracle, with a reasonably up to date patch set for that version.

Comment: I totally understand and have event thought of separating these questions into different question but then the context cannot be gained... as you see later questions are related to each others...
Oracle 9i is not supported? It is supported but it's not working as expected.

Comment: Regarding other comments,
TransactionScope does auto commits as Microsoft says and this has been working for me with MSSQL.
In the reference article you can go and check again that, there are also people like me who were not able to solve this issue even after recompiling the package! (Well in my case I don't have package by I did not mind in recompiling my procedures).
How I was returning scalars? With return values as I have been doing in MSSQL but since stored procedure stopped working, I was left with no choices.

Comment: I should agree and cross check on point 3.3 (I do have multiple connection for same database) so that could be one of the reason. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Let me elaborate more in detail, 
In the link that I posted above, see comment of this user "gdarling - oracle" who mentioned that patching database version from 9207 to 9208 solves the problem. In my case, the database version is 9206. The client is having a huge ERP developed on this version, they never have upgrade their database version in last 20 years and they are not ready to take any chance for chaning their version. the last time they made their system offline was in 2003 for few minutes only! So upgrading the database version is also not a choice here for me!

Comment: I am 100% certain that TransactionScope does not autocommit.  You'd have to show me where scope.Complete() is not required.

Comment: Sorry to hear about the customers inability to patch - that puts you you a tough place to write modern software with any sort of reliable results.  Without patching, all you have is workarounds.